# PHP profile update page MySql Error

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can anyone see the error in this code as the code is only giving me back :

> the name does not exist

It was all working fine now it does not.

If anyone can spot it please and correct me as I am still new to this.

```
<?php
    // see if the form has been completed
    include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    // Initialize any variables that the page might echo
    $username = "";
    $firstname = "";
    $surname = "";
    $gender = "Male";
    $country = "";
    $weight = "";
    $height = "";

    if(isset($_GET["u"])){
        $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

    // check if the user exists in the database
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $username = $row ["username"];
        $firstname = $row["firstname"];
        $surname = $row["surname"];
        $weight = $row["weight"];
        $height = $row["height"];
        $email = $row["email"];
        $gender = $row ["gender"];
        }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $weight = $_POST['weight'];
        $height = $_POST['height'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];

        mysql_connect ("host","****","*****"); mysql_select_db('db_k1003140');
        // check if that user exist 
        $exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='" . $username . "'") or die ("query cant connect");    
        if (mysql_num_rows ($exists) != 0) {
        // update the description in the database       
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET firstname='$firstname', surname='$surname', weight='$weight', height='$height' WHERE username='$username'") or die ("update could not be applied");
            echo "successful";
        } else echo "the name does not exist";  
     }
?>
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Profile Update: <?php echo $u; ?></title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #updateform{
        margin-top:24px;    
        }
        #updateform > div {
            margin-top: 12px;   
        }
        #updateform > input {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 3px;
            background: #F3F9DD;
        }       
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <?php include_once("template_pageTop.php"); ?>
    <div id="pageMiddle">       
    <div id="usernamecss"> Username: <?php echo $username; ?></div>
    <form action="update.php" method="POST" id="updateform">
    <div>

    <div>First Name: </div>
    <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname?>" maxlength="16">
    <div>Surname: </div>
    <input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $surname?>" maxlength="16">
    <div>Weight: </div>
    <input id="weight" type="text" name="weight" value="<?php echo $weight?>" >
    <div>Height: </div>
    <input id="height" type="text" name="height" value="<?php echo $height?>" >


    <p> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update Description"></p>

    <a href="user.php<?php echo "?u=",$username;?>">Go to Profile</a>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php include_once("template_pageBottom.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand, when do you have this message? When you click sur go to profile or when you click sur Update Description? What did you change recently on your code or environnement?

Comment: Your code has a serious SQL injection flaw: you're taking `$_POST['username']` and assembling a query without attempting to check it's valid. Anyone could tamper with this field and compromise your database.

Comment: and how you get $_GET['u'] variable?

Comment: Apart from your problem; your code is unsafe (directly using $_POST in your queries), using deprecated functions (mysql_*), has errors and your DB credentials are now public.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess you comparing `username` field with `firstname`,

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='" . $username . "'";
```

While it needs to be,

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'";
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).